# Java beginner- Can somebody debug my code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Practice {

  public static void main(String[] args){
      int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16, 17};
      getSmall(numbers);
  }

  public static void getSmall(int[] ar){
    int small=0;

    for(int i=0; i<ar.length; i++){

      if(ar[i]<small)

       small = ar[i];

    }
   System.out.println(small);
   }
}
```

The program is to find the smallest number in the array, there is no compiler error but it doesn't show the correct result.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: To start with (and not a very good idea) Use `System.out.println` to see what values are printed

Comment: This question is too localized.

Comment: what is the value of small getting printed ?

Comment: Its a kind or homework. Try using Arrays class

Comment: Your debugger can help debug your code. I suggest you try it first.

Answer (score 3):

```
  public static void getSmall(int[] ar){
    int small=ar[0];

    for(int i=1; i<ar.length; i++){

      if(ar[i]<small)

       small = ar[i];

    }
   System.out.println(small);
   }
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the length of `ar`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `small` initially to 0 is a bad idea as you are hoping that your array contains an element less than that for the answer to be correct.

A common idiom is to initialise `small` to `ar[0]` (having, of course, first checked that `ar` contains at least 1 element). Then run your loop from 1.

```
for(int i = 1;
```

(I dislike initialising `small` to a very large number since that puts the answer to your function in an undefined state if `ar` does not have any elements.)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int small = 0
```

to

```
int small = ar[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't init small=0, 
change to `int small = ar[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
int small=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

in place of

```
int small=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

this code will print `small` value, give the max of integer

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
public static void getSmall(int[] ar) {
    int small = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i] < small)
            small = ar[i];
    }
    System.out.println(small);
}
```

to

```
public static void getSmall(int[] ar) {
    int small = ar[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i] < small)
            small = ar[i];
    }
    System.out.println(small);
}
```

because variable `small` is not assigned to any value from your array